# IAM error when authenticating with token SurrealDB

Tags: jwt, surrealdb

I have recently added the `--auth` flag to make my instance of SurrealDB production ready as suggested in the [documentation](https://docs.surrealdb.com/docs/cli/start#authentication).

Upon doing so, my users can no longer view their data as this error is returned when authenticating with JWT tokens: `{"code":403,"details":"Forbidden","description":"Not allowed to do this.","information":"There was a problem with the database: IAM error: Not enough permissions to perform this action"}`

Removing the `--auth` flag allows this authentication, but this goes against the production ready recommendation.

**SAMPLE JWT TOKEN CONTENT**

```json
{
  "ns": "Test",
  "db": "Test",
  "sc": "account",
  "tk": "user_tkn",
  "id": "users:test_user",
  "iat": 1703421361,
  "exp": 1703424961
}
```

**SAMPLE REQUEST**

```bash
curl -X POST "https://database.com/sql" \
     -H "Content-Type: text/plain" \
     -H "Accept: application/json" \
     -H "Token: <HS256 TOKEN HERE>" \
     -H "NS: Test" \
     -H "DB: Test" \
     -H "SC: account" \
     -d "SELECT * FROM users:⟨+44XXXXXXXXXX⟩"
```

For testing purposes, I have given `PERMISSIONS FULL` to the `users` table.

**INFO FOR SCOPE**

```json
{
    "tokens": {
        "user_tkn": "DEFINE TOKEN user_tkn ON SCOPE account TYPE HS256 VALUE 'example123456'"
    }
}
```

**Additional Info**

Start Command: `surreal start --auth --deny-guests --no-banner`

Protocol: `HTTPS`

SurrealDB Version: `1.0.2 for linux on x86_64`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the `--auth` argument is indeed very recommended for production deployments and it is not necessarily to remove it to solve your problem. Your issue happens because you are providing the token in the `Token` header, whereas you should provide it [in the `Authorization` header](https://docs.surrealdb.com/docs/integration/http#sql) in the format `Bearer $token`. Assuming that the JWT is being constructed and signed correctly, this should solve your issue.

Here is how I would reproduce what I understand is your intended use case:

1. Start the server with `surreal start --auth -u root -p root --deny-guests --no-banner`. Remember to change the root credentials in your deployment.
2. Connect to the server with `surreal sql -u root -p root` and run the following statements:

```sql
use ns Test db Test;
DEFINE SCOPE account;
DEFINE TOKEN user_tkn ON SCOPE account TYPE HS256 VALUE 'example123456';
DEFINE TABLE users PERMISSIONS FULL; -- Remember to properly restrict this.
CREATE users:test_user CONTENT {"exists": true};
```

3. Create a token (e.g. in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/)) with the HS256 algorithm and using `example123456` as the signature secret. Do not check the box to encode the secret. The token payload should contain the following:

```json
{
  "ns": "Test",
  "db": "Test",
  "sc": "account",
  "tk": "user_tkn",
  "id": "users:test_user",
  "iat": 1703421361,
  "exp": 1803424961
}
```

4. Assuming that you are running SurrealDB locally as I described, you can then execute queries using the token that you just generated with HTTP requests like the one generated by the following command:

```bash
curl -vvv localhost:8000/sql \
--data "SELECT * from users:test_user" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJucyI6IlRlc3QiLCJkYiI6IlRlc3QiLCJzYyI6ImFjY291bnQiLCJ0ayI6InVzZXJfdGtuIiwiaWQiOiJ1c2Vyczp0ZXN0X3VzZXIiLCJpYXQiOjE3MDM0MjEzNjEsImV4cCI6MTgwMzQyNDk2MX0.SsuApbUvBxsOvO8T5nvtJ294bsUbdynits77dgiETT8"
```

Following the instructions above, you should get the following response:

```json
[{"result":[{"exists":true,"id":"users:test_user"}],"status":"OK","time":"97.48µs"}]
```

I hope this was helpful! Feel free to let me know if you need any other help.

PS: I work in SurrealDB.

Comment: The JWT is in the format as written in the post, signed with the same key using HS256. ```{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}```

Comment: I tried authenticating using the `Authorization: Bearer <token>` header and I get this output from the exact curl command you sent me (with a fresh token and the correct host): ```bash < HTTP/2 401 < date: Tue, 09 Jan 2024 18:08:54 GMT < content-length: 39 < cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC < alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400 * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23): * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23): * Connection #0 to host (url here like test.db.com) left intact There was a problem with authentication``` I've omitted chunk of the response, these are the last relevant lines.

Comment: Did you also create the resources using the SurrealQL queries that I posted? That format for the JWT is fine, just make sure that the `exp` claim has a timestamp that is not already expired, like the one in your original post. As for the error, I would need to see the logs in the server to help you figure out what may be going wrong in your case. Feel free to post here the logs that you see when running the server with `--log trace` parameter or, if you want, [join our Discord](https://discord.gg/surrealdb) where we may be able to better help you.

Comment: I started a thread on the discord and tagged you. It seems the issue doe indeed have to do with the `exp` claim, but the UNIX time is not actually expired.

Comment: In case someone finds this question in the future, we discussed the issue on Discord and found that the backend that @nxfi777 was using was not signing the token with the same secret that was defined in SurrealDB.